# Assigning sliced python dataframes into variables in lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists

```
List_1 =[“Category_1”,”Category_2”,”Category_3”]
List_2 =[x,y,z]
```

In my database, there's a lot of data corresponding to those three categories. This is the mechanical way of doing a pandas operation that I want to eventually make shorter.

```
x = database1.loc[database1[‘Categories’] == ‘Catergory_1’]
y = database1.loc[database1[‘Categories’] == ‘Catergory_2’]
Z = database1.loc[database1[‘Categories’] == ‘Catergory_3’]
```

I tried shortening this by using a for loop

```
for i,j in zip(List_1,List_2):
   j = database1.loc[database1['Categories'] == i]
```

The error I get is:

```
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

How do I go about converting that into a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your variables x, y, z do not defined and you get the error.

You can set an empty List_2 and store in it the result of operation:

```
List_1 =['Category_1','Category_2','Category_3']
List_2 = list()

for i in List_1:
   List_2.append(database1.loc[database1['Categories'] == i])

print (List_2)
```

If you prefer variables x, y, z then init them in the start of program before defining the lists:

```
x=y=z=None
List_1 =['Category_1','Category_2','Category_3']
List_2 = [x,y,z]
```

Comment: try to use the standard `snake_case` for variable names, and use `list_2.append(database1.loc[database1['Categories'] == i])` instead of `+=`